# Spring boot, mvc, hibernate and mysql configuration - sessionFactory error

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new in spring boot. I want to configure spring boot with mysql, hibernate, jpa and jsp. When i want to start it i gen an error: "Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' etc.", more in stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/budget/configs/DatabaseConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class name must not be null
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:732) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at com.budget.HomeBudgetApplication.main(HomeBudgetApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class name must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.convertClassNameToResourcePath(ClassUtils.java:960) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.scanPackages(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:282) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:434) ~[spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
... 16 common frames omitted
```

pom.xml `4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.budget</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>homeBudget</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<packaging>war</packaging>
```

`

HomeBudgetApplication.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration()
@ComponentScan({"com.budget.*"})
public class HomeBudgetApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(HomeBudgetApplication.class, args);

}
}
```

DatabaseConfig.java

```
 @Configuration
 @ComponentScan("com.budget.*")
 @EnableWebMvc
 @EnableTransactionManagement
 @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class DatabaseConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("com.budget.*"));
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
    return sessionFactoryBean;
}

private Properties hibProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("spring.jpa.database-platform", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.database-platform"));
    properties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
    properties.put("spring.jpa.show-sql", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));
    return properties;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}
}
```

application.properties

```
'spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/budget
 spring.datasource.username=marcin
 spring.datasource.password=marcin123
 spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
 spring.jpa.show-sql=true
 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
 entitymanager.packages.to.scan=com.budget'
```

Comment: Why do you even need a `SessionFactory`.... You state you want to use JPA. Next to that you want to use Spring Boot but in your configuration you try very hard NOT to use spring boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use the framework and not work around the framework. You also state you want to use Spring Boot and JPA but your configuraiton shows you are trying very hard not to use Spring Boot and that you don't use JPA but plain hibernate.

First remove your `DatabaseConfig`. (Yes remove it).

Move your `HomeBudgetApplication` to `com.bugdet` and remove all annotations and replace with a simple `@SpringBootApplication`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HomeBudgetApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HomeBudgetApplication.class, args);    
    }
}
```

In your `application.properties` add `spring.mvc.view` properties to have the `InternalResourceViewResolver` automatically configured. ALso remove the `entitymanager.packages.to.scan` as that is added for you already.

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/budget
spring.datasource.username=marcin
spring.datasource.password=marcin123
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Everything else will be configured by Spring Boot. It will detect your web, jpa and transactions and will automatically configure it.

If you have any repository etc. based on `SessionFactory` replace it to work on the `EntityManager` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You scan the packages twice on `HomeBudgetApplication` and `DatabasebaseConfig`.
Delete componenet scan on `DatabasebaseConfig`.

Good luck

Comment: I deleted component scan on DatabaseConfig but it didn't resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="${jdbc.databaseurl}" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.kdkce.erp.entity" />
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.format.sql">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.2.2.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    <hibernate-version>5.0.2.Final</hibernate-version>
    <spring-security-version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring-security-version>
    <mysql-version>5.1.9</mysql-version>
</properties>
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- new dependency added for spring jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```